# Is Eastern diamondback rattlesnake swimming is an adaptation?

Tags: snake

Is Eastern diamondback rattlesnake swimming is an adaptation?
I read that they are capable swimmers. Can we consider that as an adaptation?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: I think a better question is." Are there any snakes that can't swim?"